# I want to call jquery function on that where a tag have title start with http

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i don't know what i have to use jquery function where we use like keyword in php i want same jquery should call when some  tag have title or href contains some url like start with HTTP it should call on click jquery then i want to change CSS on a popup.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("#contentBox > ul.portfolioitems.portfolio4columns > li > div > a").;
})
```

Comment: how about `$("[href^='http']")`. Post your HTML also.

Comment: i use it but it is not working basically i have to put this jquery on dynamic site mean when you open the site it will show all content in pop up which shows in fade out , then there are images like portfolio there are logos, websites, i want this jquery should work on just websites when i click some of image like website it also load and show in second pop up there i want to add jquery width and it should scroll with mouse so every website can easily look up by end user . there is now small website looking because of website images height.

Comment: http://depictors.net/#!four-colums-filter/

see my site there is web section i want to add css scrolling and width when any item clicked on web portfolio . how i can do that